# "Three-bonacchi" sequence

Tags: python, algorithm, sequence, fibonacci

We have a sequence with first 3 elements:
`t_1 = t_2 = t_3 = 1`

The rest of the sequence is defined by rule:
`t_n = t_(n-1) + t_(n-2) + t_(n-3)` (like Fibonacci sequence but for 3 numbers).

```
t = {1; 1; 1; 3; 5; 9; 17; 31; ...}
```

The task is to find the N-th odd number which isn't a divider of any element of the sequence.

```
Input: N (1 <= N <= 10^4 )

Output: N-th number which satisfies the condition.
```

Example:

```
Input: 125

Output: 2025
```

My straight solution works too slow. How should I improve/change the algorithms to finish the work in 1 second with given restrictions (N <= 10^4)?

```
t = [1, 1, 1]
N = int(input())  # find N-th odd number which isn't a divider of any number in the sequence
counter = 0  # how many appropriate numbers we've already found
curr_number = 1  # number to check

for i in range(100000):
    t.append(t[-1] + t[-2] + t[-3])


while counter < N:
    curr_number += 2

    for i in range(len(t)):
        if t[i] % curr_number == 0:
            break
    else:
        counter += 1

print(curr_number)
```

Comment: Given the _infinite_ sequence `t` (erm - the …`t`, not the one from the code block), why would it suffice to test divisibility up to the `10×N`th term? (What is `range(100000)` supposed to signify?)

Comment: I agree that it's not enough for any finite number of elements is the sequence. I just cannot generalize the idea of finding appropriate numbers.

Comment: @greybeard: it's [project euler #225](https://projecteuler.net/problem=225)

Comment: @nofake: How long can the sequence t_1%d, t_2%d, t_3%d ... be before it repeats?

Comment: @rici 1 second for N=10**4 is a lot harder than the proj. Euler question.

Comment: @paulHankin: Yeah, it seems like some kind of generalization of Euler 225. But that's still a useful search term. Of course, the time restriction could also be overcome by throwing more hardware at the problem.

Comment: t_n % 885 repeats only after 1427023 iterations. So it doesn't seem like checking the first 100000 Tribonacci numbers for divisibility is enough.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Yeah, the cycle length seems to be quadratic, although I haven't tried to prove that. That would make the naive computation (that is, the one usually provided for Euler225) cubic in N; my naive little C program just computed F(10000) as 134241 in 1323.7 seconds (i5 laptop), so some more number theory (or a rack of serious CPUs) would be needed to get it down to 1 second.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Actually, it wasn't number theory that was lacking A little common sense and a sieve got it down to 13.5 seconds. (That's the time to build the sieve up to 10000 entries.)

Comment: I'm not sure we've arrived at a good enough answer for it to be accepted yet, frankly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in Project Euler's [description](https://projecteuler.net/problem=225) of this problem:

> It can be shown that 27 does not divide any terms of this sequence.

To prove this, you obviously don't calculate the tribonacci sequence to infinity to check that 27 doesn't divide any of the numbers. There must be a mathematical shortcut to prove this, and if we can find this shortcut, we can use it to check whether other numbers divide the tribonacci sequence.

Checking whether a number is divided by 27 is the same as checking whether the number modulo 27 equals 0.

If we take the tribonacci sequence modulo 27, we get:

```
  1 % 27 =  1  
  1 % 27 =  1  
  1 % 27 =  1  
  3 % 27 =  3  
  5 % 27 =  5  
  9 % 27 =  9  
 17 % 27 = 17  
 31 % 27 =  4  
 57 % 27 =  3  
105 % 27 = 24  
193 % 27 =  4
...
```

You'll notice that in order to find that 193 % 27 = 4, we don't need to use the number 193 (because it equals 31 + 57 + 105) and we could just use the modulo's of the previous three numbers:

```
(4 + 3 + 24) % 27 = 4
```

This means we don't need the actual tribonacci sequence to check whether 27 divides it. We only need to look through the sequence of modulo's to check whether we find a zero:

```
  1            % 27 =  1  
  1            % 27 =  1  
  1            % 27 =  1  
( 1 +  1 +  1) % 27 =  3
( 1 +  1 +  3) % 27 =  5  
( 1 +  3 +  5) % 27 =  9  
( 3 +  5 +  9) % 27 = 17  
( 5 +  9 + 17) % 27 =  4  
( 9 + 17 +  4) % 27 =  3  
(17 +  4 +  3) % 27 = 24  
( 4 +  3 + 24) % 27 =  4  
...
```

Since this sequence only contains numbers below 27, there is a limited number of possibilities for any three consecutive numbers, and at some point three consecutive numbers will appear that have already appeared earlier in the sequence.

Any three specific numbers will always result in the same fourth number, which means that if a combination of three consecutive numbers is repeated, the whole sequence thereafter will be repeated. So if no zero has been found, and the sequence starts to repeat, you know there will never be a zero, and the number doesn't divide the tribonacci sequence.

It is also important to note that any three consecutive numbers in the sequence can only be the result of a specific previous number; e.g. the sequence [3, 24, 4] can only be preceeded by the number 4. This means that the repetition will start from the beginning of the sequence. So to check whether the sequence repeats before a zero is found, we only have to find a repetition of the first three numbers: [1, 1, 1].

This also means we don't have to store the whole sequence while we're calculating it, we can keep replacing [a, b, c] by [b, c, (a + b + c) % n], and comparing them with [1, 1, 1].

In the case of 27, the sequence repeats after 117 numbers:

```
1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 4, 3, 24, 4, 4, 5, 13, 22, 13, 21, 2, 9, 5, 16, 3, 24, 16, 16, 2, 7, 25, 7, 12, 17, 9, 11, 10, 3, 24, 10, 10, 17, 10, 10, 10, 3, 23, 9, 8, 13, 3, 24, 13, 13, 23, 22, 4, 22, 21, 20, 9, 23, 25, 3, 24, 25, 25, 20, 16, 7, 16, 12, 8, 9, 2, 19, 3, 24, 19, 19, 8, 19, 19, 19, 3, 14, 9, 26, 22, 3, 24, 22, 22, 14, 4, 13, 4, 21, 11, 9, 14, 7, 3, 24, 7, 7, 11, 25, 16, 25, 12, 26, 9, 20, 1, 3, 24, 1, 1, 26, 1, 1, 1 ...
```

So the algorithm to check whether a number n divides the tribonacci sequence would be:

> - Start with the numbers a = 1, b = 1, c = 1
> - Calucate d = (a + b + c) % n
> - If d = 0 return true *(n divides a number from the tribonacci sequence)*
> - Set a = b, b = c, c = d
> - If a = 1 and b = 1 and c = 1 return false *(beginning of repetition found)*
> - Repeat with new values for a, b and c

---

This code example will work for any value of N, but it's obviously not fast enough to find the 10000th odd non-dividing number (which is 134241) in less than a second.

```js
var N = 125, n = 1, count = 0;
while (count < N) {
    var a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d;
    n += 2;
    while (d = (a + b + c) % n) {
        a = b; b = c; c = d;
        if (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1) {
            ++count;
            break;
        }
    }
}
document.write(N + ": " + n);
```

I found that the first zero always comes before the first identical triplet [a=b=c], not just before [1,1,1], so you can change the test to `a == b && b == c` to make it run about three times faster.

```js
var N = 125, n = 1, count = 0;
while (count < N) {
    var a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d;
    n += 2;
    while (d = (a + b + c) % n) {
        a = b; b = c; c = d;
        if (a == b && b == c) {
            ++count;
            break;
        }
    }
}
document.write(N + ": " + n);
```

But even when using C instead of JavaScript, finding the 10000th odd non-dividing number with this method takes minutes rather than seconds. Further improvements can be made using the sieve idea from @rici's answer, but if it's really possible to get it down below one second there must be an additional mathematical shortcut that's still eluding us.

---

The code example below uses an incremental sieve, so that it doesn't need to have a predefined size, and can be used for any value of N. When a value n is tested and found to be a non-divider, its first odd multiple 3×n is set to the value n, or if that is already marked as a multiple of another non-divider, 5×n or 7×n or ... is set to n. When a value n is considered that is marked as a multiple of a non-divider in the sieve, the mark is moved to the next odd multiple of that non-divider.

```js
function Sieve() {                          // incremental sieve
    this.array = [];                        // associative array
}
Sieve.prototype.add = function(n) {
    var base = n;
    while (this.array[n += (2 * base)]);    // find first unset odd multiple of n
    this.array[n] = base;                   // set to base value
}
Sieve.prototype.check = function(n) {
    var base = this.array[n];               // get base value
    if (! base) return false;               // if not set, return
    delete this.array[n];                   // delete current multiple
    while (this.array[n += (2 * base)]);    // find next unset odd multiple
    this.array[n] = base;                   // set to base value
    return true;
}
function dividesTribonacci(n) {
    var a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d;
    while (d = (a + b + c) % n) {
        a = b; b = c; c = d;
        if (a == b && b == c) return false; // identical triple found
    }
    return true;                            // zero found, n divides tribonacci
}
function NthOddNonDivider(N) {
    var n = 1, count = 0, sieve = new Sieve();
    while (count < N) {
        while (sieve.check(n += 2)) {       // skip multiples of non-dividers
            if (++count == N) return n;
        }
        if (! dividesTribonacci(n)) {
            ++count;
            sieve.add(n);
        }
    }
    return n;
}
document.write(NthOddNonDivider(125));      // 2025
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136671/discussion-on-answer-by-m69-three-bonacchi-sequence).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to solve this problem for N=10<sup>4</sup> in less than a second, at least without parallel processing. But I managed to do it in 10 seconds with a commodity laptop, which is at least in the vicinity.

The naive brute-force solution of simply running through the series modulo each odd number in turn looking for either a 0 or a repetition of the start configuration is certainly adequate for small values of N, but its time complexity is (apparently) O(N<sup>3</sup>); to count the first 10,000 non-divisors took about 22 minutes on my laptop. The problem is that the period length is O(N<sup>2</sup>) for many moduli, so some of the trials involve thousands of millions of steps. Even though the inner loop is trivial, when you perform hundreds of thousands of computations of thousands of millions steps each, it is going to take a while.

But there is an extremely effective way to prune the search, starting with the simple observation that if `k` does not divide any tribonacci number, then neither does `3k` or `5k` or, indeed, any other multiple of `k`. [Note 1]

So a simple sieve can avoid a great number of trials. Every time we find a non-divisor, we mark all of its multiples (up to some limit) as being non-divisors, and then we don't have to investigate the period of those moduli. That simple solution brought the computation time down by two decimal orders of magnitude, from 1320 seconds to 10 seconds.

Also, with the sieve, the observed time complexity went from O(N<sup>3</sup>) to O(N<sup>2</sup>). There are a couple of reasons for this, and I haven't done enough analysis to provide definite proofs so I don't know if the complexity will stay quadratic as N gets larger. (Indeed, I don't even have a proof that the complexity of the naive algorithm is cubic; without some kind of numerical analysis it is impossible to say that the Tribonacci period of some modulus `i` is less than `i3`, which would make testing `n` moduli O(n<sup>4</sup>), but after testing a couple of hundred thousand moduli, I didn't find a single one whose period length was even close to the square of the modulus.

(I'm going to write `π(k)` for the period length of the tribonacci sequence modulo `k`; the usual name for this function is the [Pisano period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period), and `π(k)` is a common notation.)

The [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) is sufficient to show that if `j` and `k` are coprime (i.e. they have no prime factors in common), then `π(jk) = LCM(π(j), π(k))` (LCM is the [Least Common Multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)). That means that we can easily compute `π(k)` given the prime factorization of `k`, if we have the values of `π(p)` for all primes and powers of primes. The important point, though, for this algorithm is that compound numbers tend to have large periods, because the period lengths being combined with least common multiple tend to have few common factors, so the LCM approximates a product. Also, if `p` is a prime, `π(pe)` is usually `pe−1×π(p)`. (It is always a divisor of `pe−1×π(p)`, but in the vast majority of cases the equality holds.)

The sieve is reasonably good at filtering out the need for examining compound numbers; it also filters out powers of primes once it finds a power which is a non-divisor. The end result is that most of the moduli actually investigated have shorter periods. In particular, for reasons I do not yet understand, the period of <s>all</s>most non-divisor primes (as far as I was able to test, the only exception is 1,574,029) is less than the prime itself, so it can be found rapidly. And since there are usually a lot of zeros in any sequence which contains a zero, a divisor can also be found reasonably rapidly (Although it sometimes requires examining more than the first `k` values of the sequence modulo `k`, it never comes close to `k²`.)

All of that means that between sieving known multiples of non-divisors and stopping the scan when a modulus is shown to be a divisor, it is rare to do a large period scan; in computing the first 10,000 non-divisors, the longest scan of a single modulus was only a few million.

---

#### Notes

1. The same cannot be said of divisors: the fact that `k` does divide some tribonacci number says nothing about whether multiples of `k` will be divisors or not.